# Publisher extension for .sink

Tags: swift, combine, publisher

I've made an extension for Publisher to simplify sink, but my backend (not made by me) is messed up and I have a custom error that shouldn't be an error, and I want to return .success.

```swift
extension Publisher {
    func sinkToResult(_ result: @escaping ((Result<Self.Output, Self.Failure>) -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable {
        return sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                if let error = error as? ApiError, let globalError = error.globalErrors.first, globalError.code == 2233 {
                    //Here i want to send something like return(.success(true))
                }
                result(.failure(error))
            case .finished:
                break
            }
        }, 
        receiveValue: { output in
            result(.success(output))
        })
    }
}
```

Can you help me to create a custom Output.Self type that I can return here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options:

```
enum MyResult<T> {
  case noError
  case object(T)
}
```

and then change func signature to:
`func sinkToResult(_ result: @escaping ((Result<MyResult<Self.Output>, Self.Failure>) -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable`

Or you can wrap `Result` and add your specific case:

```
enum MyResult<Success, Failure: Error> {
  case noError
  case result(Result<Success, Failure>)
}
```

and change signature to:
`func sinkToResult(_ result: @escaping ((MyResult<Self.Output, Self.Failure>) -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable`.

Either way, I think it would be better to handle this directly when you perform the JSON decoding.

Comment: Thnak you! Unfortunately the problem is that in this case I don't have any JSON, only a simple text response from server, so my API call always gives me error (I'm using a custom component with Alamofire). So I have to do this workaround for now

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `tryCatch` before you get to sink

```
func tryCatch<P>(_ handler: @escaping (Self.Failure) throws -> P) -> Publishers.TryCatch<Self, P> where P : Publisher, Self.Output == P.Output
```

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/tryallsatisfy/trycatch(_:)) say:

> Handles errors from an upstream publisher by either replacing it with
> another publisher or throwing a new error.

You could just add it as the last step in your pipeline:

```
///...
.tryCatch { error in
    if let error = error as? ApiError, let globalError = error.globalErrors.first, globalError.code == 2233 {
        return Just(true)
    } else {
        throw error
    }
}
```

It would be difficult to make this generic if you wanted this publisher to return something different depending on circumstances (i.e `true` or an empty `Array` etc.)